# What happens to gnome shell when I upgrade to 12.04?

Tags: upgrade, gnome, 12.04

What happens to my gnome shell session if I upgrade to ubuntu 12.04, I removed unity. and gnome has many extensions and modifications via ppa etc.

So,  what happens if I choose to upgrade?
I supose that unity will be installed, no problem whith that, but how this affects gnome shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same setup on my desktop and laptop and upgraded them both.

On my desktop I used the alternate iso to upgrade and after rebooting, I got a gnome related error when I tried to login.

On my laptop I used the update manager and it worked perfectly. I was able to login and gnome-shell was still my default desktop environment.

I suspect it failed on my desktop, because I told it not to download updates while it was upgrading.

Comment: The PPA might be problematic too.

Comment: Now I have no audio, and a temporal solution it's 
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*
but every time I turn it off again, the problem comeback.